# How to correctly think about number of microstates of a system?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

I am currently learning statistical mechanics and am finding it a bit difficult to intuitively grasp the concept of the number of microstates for a given macrostate. As a simple example, consider the free expansion of one mole of gas from a volume $V_1$ into a larger volume $V_1 + V_2$. The change in entropy for this process is
$$\Delta S = R \ln \left(\frac{V_1 + V_2}{V_1}\right) = k_B N_A \ln \left(\frac{V_1 + V_2}{V_1}\right) = k_B \ln \left[\left(\frac{V_1}{V_1 + V_2}\right)^{-N_A}\right].$$
The standard argument then given in my book is that the probability of a single molecule being in the original volume $V_1$ is $\frac{V_1}{V_1+V_2}$ so that the probability of the initial state in which all $N_A$ molecules are in volume $V_1$ is $p_1=\left(\frac{V_1}{V_1+V_2}\right)^{N_A}.$ The probability of the final state in which each of the the molecules is in any place within the volume $V_1 + V_2$ is $p_2 = 1$. Hence, the ratio of probabilities is $\frac{p_2}{p_1} = \left(\frac{V_1}{V_1 + V_2}\right)^{-N_A}.$ The claim made at this point is that the ratio of the number of microstates for the the final state ($W_2$) to the number of microstates for the initial state initial state ($W_1$) is given by
$$\frac{W_2}{W_1} = \frac{p_2}{p_1} = \left(\frac{V_1}{V_1 + V_2}\right)^{-N_A}.$$
Therefore, we have
$$\Delta S = k_B \ln\left(\frac{W_2}{W_1}\right)$$
and this is the justification given for the Boltzmann formula. From a purely mathematical point of view, this derivation makes a lot of sense. What I am confused about is the exact nature of $W_1$ and $W_2$. It makes sense that if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are both finite quantities, then the ratio $\frac{W_2}{W_1} = \frac{p_2}{p_1}$ must hold. However, suppose I begin with a system in a given microstate for state $1$ in which all the particles are contained within the volume $V_1$. Then, since the volume $V_1$ contains an uncountably infinite number of points and I can place each of the $N_A$ molecules at any of these points, it feels like $W_1$ should be uncountably infinite. Similarly, $W_2$ should be infinite and the ratio $\frac{W_2}{W_1}$ would not make sense. Also, not every state for which all the molecules are in the volume $V_1$ would correspond to the same macrostate (for example, all of the molecules occupy one fourth of that volume) so I'm not sure why all of these possible states are counted in $W_1$. I'm hoping someone can explain the correct way to think about the quantities $W_1$ and $W_2$ and why both of these quantities are (large) finite numbers.

Comment: As you correctly observe, $W_i$ as "number of states" only really makes sense if the phase space is quantized in some way, having countable discrete states. A more general notion is that of _phase space volume_, and this is the correct concept in the case of a classical gas, as here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a quantized system, i.e. one with discrete configurations, the quantity $W$ is simply a count of the number of microscopic states compatible with a particular macroscopic state. For a system with continuous degrees of freedom this must be generalized, because there will generally be an uncountable set of microstates compatible with a particular macroscopic state.

If your system consists of $N$ particles in 3 dimensions, then it will be described by $3N$ position variables $q_1, \dotsc, q_{3N}$ and $3N$ momentum variables $p_1, \dotsc p_{3N}$. The *phase space volume* $W$ of a particular macrostate is then defined as

$$W = C \int dq_1 \dotsc dq_{3N} dp_1 \dotsc dp_{3N},$$

where the integral is taken over all configurations (microstates) compatible with the macrostate. The proportionality constant $C$ depends both on convention and whether or not the particles are *distinguishable*, but you are safe to ignore that subtlety for now.

Now, phase space volume behaves much like a microstate count, which is why it is often safe to think about it as such. For example, suppose that the $q_i$ are just the $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-coordinates of the particles in a classical gas, and suppose they are confined to a container of volume $V$. Then

$$\int dq_1 \dotsc dq_{3N} = \left( \int dx \, dy \, dz \right)^N = V^N.$$

Hence if you start with a container of volume $V_1$ and change its volume to $V_1 + V_2$, keeping all else fixed, you will find that

$$\frac{W_2}{W_1} = \frac{C \, (V_1 + V_2)^N \int dp_1 \dotsc dp_{3N}}{C \, V_1^N \int dp_1 \dotsc dp_{3N}} = \left( \frac{V_1 + V_2}{V_1} \right)^N,$$

which, as you can see, is consistent with the discretized argument outlined in the original question.

---

### Addendum

In the above I tried to make the presentation as simple as possible while retaining the most important points, but in doing so I brushed over some technical details. At the request of the OP I will now go into those details.

The macroscopic state of the system has a certain total energy $E$ associated with it, so the integral in the definition of $W$ needs to be restricted to those values of $q = (q_1, \dotsc, q_{3N})$ and $p = (p_1, \dotsc, p_{3N})$ that satisfy $H(q,p) = E$, where $H$ is the [Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_mechanics) of the system. There is a technical issue here, because this condition determines a $(6N-1)$-dimensional region (a hypersurface), and hence the integral will be zero. The region will have zero width, so to speak; think of the *volume* of a surface in 3D, the *area* of a line in 2D, the *length* of a point in 1D. What we really want to measure is the, let's say, "hyperarea" of this hypersurface. To do so we adopt the more technical definition

$$W = C \int \delta(H(q,p) - E) \, dq_1 \dotsc dq_{3N} dp_1 \dotsc dp_{3N},$$

where $\delta$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

To retain the results above, consider an ideal gas, having Hamiltonian

$$H(q,p) = \sum_{i=1}^{3N} \frac{p_i^2}{2 m}.$$

This Hamiltonian is independent of the position variables, hence

$$W = C \int dq_1 \dotsc dq_{3N} \int \delta(H(q,p) - E) \, dp_1 \dotsc dp_{3N},$$

and you can check for yourself that we once again get

$$\frac{W_2}{W_1} = \left( \frac{V_1 + V_2}{V_1} \right)^N$$

in the OPs scenario. (Note however that this result holds because of the specific form of the Hamiltonian, which lets us separate the integral into a position part and a momentum part. This is not always possible, but it is possible for the ideal gas.)

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot. One quick question: in the integrals in the ratio W_2/W_1, what region is each integral over (I assume this is a region of phase space with the position bounds corresponding to the volume V_1 and V_1 + V_2, but I'm not sure what the momentun region would be) and why do the integrals involving momenta cancel?

Comment: The momentum region is determined by the energy $E$ in the system. For a noninteracting gas the energy is just the sum of the kinetic energies of the particles, i.e. $E = \sum_{i=1}^{3N} p_i^2 / 2 m_i$. This condition constrains the momenta, giving the region of integration. The momentum integrals cancel because they are unaffected by the container volume.

Comment: There is an extra subtlety here that I brushed over. A condition like $E = \sum_i^{3N} p_i^2 / 2 m_i$ for the momentum integral actually determines a $(3N-1)$-dimensional (hyper-) surface rather than a $3N$-dimensional volume. Hence the integral, as written, becomes zero. But there are ways to "measure" this surface as well, which is what we are interested in; they are just a little more technical than what I wanted to include in the answer.

Comment: What value and units does constant $C$ have?

Comment: @JánLalinský The units of $C$ should be such that $W$ is unitless, so that $S = k_B \ln W$ makes sense. In order to avoid things like the [Gibbs paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_paradox) it should also include a factor of $1/N!$ in the case of indistinguishable particles (or analagous factors in cases of multiple species of particles). To correctly make contact with classical thermodynamics and quantum mechanics further considerations are needed, but this is more involved than I want to go into here. See for example Plischke/Bergersen, section 2.1, and references therein.

Comment: $S=k_B\ln W$ makes sense even if $W$ is not unitless, e.g. when it is phase volume with unit $(kgm^2s^{-1})^{3N}$. Logarithm of big numbers depends only weakly on units. You may impose unitless $W$ as an aesthetic desideratum, but this only fixes units of $C$, not its value.

Comment: Addition of the delta function changes units of the result the same way as dividing by energy, so to get a dimensionless quantity $W$, definition of $C$ should reflect that. But this means $C$ is not purely function of $h$, but there has to be some characteristic frequency or characteristic energy as well in $C$.

Comment: What I'm getting at it's not really obvious that the formula with the delta function is the correct way to write down the correct measure of the compatible phase space. Especially when nobody ever writes $C$ down.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with "Logarithm of big numbers depends only weakly on units". To me, taking the logarithm of a dimensional quantity makes little sense, but apparently some people disagree. Other than that I don't disagree with you. Indeed the treatment in Plischke/Bergersen does have a sort of characteristic energy $\delta E$ baked into $C$ in order to make contact with semi-classical theory.

Comment: Sorry I mixed up two different ideas, dependence on units vs dependence on whether volume of the whole phase space or the thin energy shell is taken. The resulting value of logarithm depends strongly on the units chosen, but very weakly on whether whole space or the shell is taken.

Comment: The problem with this way of describing classical theory is there is no ground for introducing energy scale $\delta E$ that defines the restriction to compatible phase space volume. So despite best efforts to define unique entropy, the result is ambiguous. I think this has to be so in classical theory, there is no way to get at value of $\delta E$ or $C$, thus the entropy expression in terms of $C$ is ambiguous as well.

Comment: Entropy value can be disambiguated only via quantum statistics, where we postulate there is one available state per phase space volume $h^{3N}$.

Comment: You might be right that we need to invoke semiclassical theory in order to fix $C$. In that case my description (in the addendum) again becomes an approximation of a sum over discrete states, and we must have $C = \delta E / h^{3N} N!$ (for indistinguishable particles).

Comment: I feel like it should be possible to make a fully classical statistical mechanics though; but it might take some care. Maybe one can argue that $C$ should contain a factor $1/h^{3N}$, where $h$ is just some constant with units of action, by considering how $W$ ought to scale with $N$? One can certainly argue that it should contain $1/N!$ for indistinguishable particles. Then $C$ must have the form $C = \delta E / N! h^{3N}$, and maybe $\delta E$ can be determined (at least to some degree) by requiring that the thermodynamic limit hold? I'm not sure.